# RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. Gunicorn + Flask

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, python-multiprocessing

I have a flask app which uses huggingface pipeline for text generation. I want use `preload` flag of gunicorn so that the model used for text generation is loaded once into memory and can be shared by gunicorn workers. However I am running into `RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method` .

I used `spawn` method in `torch.multiprocessing` as mentioned in error but problem still persists.

****init**.py**

```
import torch
torch.multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn', force=True)

from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config.from_object(Config)

from app import routes
```

**Directory structure**

```
app
 |--- __init__.py
 |--- routes.py
 |--- service.py (huggingface pipeline is initialized here)
```

**Gunicorn command**

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0 -w 4 --preload --timeout 600 app:app
```